# Returning from JavaScript function to HTML Body

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling a JavaScript function from the HTML Body using the onload event. The JavaScript function executes successfully but the HTML Body contents are not displayed.

I believe, there is an issue with returning from the JavaScript to the HTML Body.

Here is how the code looks like:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display()
{
 document.write("You just executed JavaScript code");
 return true;
}
</script>

<body onload="display();">
<p>We are in HTML now</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This will display the text, "You just executed JavaScript code" in the browser. But the innerHTML of  tags is not displayed.

I modified the onload event in  tag as:

```
<body onload="return display();">
```

And, even this executes only the JavaScript.

Comment: Is this only for test ? or you are working on some issue where this require ?

Comment: Yes it is something which I would like to know how to do.

Comment: check my answer this is the problem generated by Document.Write().Is this link helpful for you ?

Comment: Thank you Sunny and everyone else. Yes, these are helpful and I am reading to understand it better.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to show the message as alert try this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function display()
 {
 alert("You just executed JavaScript code");
 return true;
 }
</script>
</head>
 <html>
 <body onload="display();">
 <p>We are in HTML now</p>
</body>
```

else

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload=function()
 {
document.getElementById("js").innerHTML = "You just executed JavaScript code";
return true;
}
</script>
<body>
<p id="js"></p>
<p>We are in HTML now</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write

Once the document has finished loading, calling `document.write()` will actually first call `document.open()`, which replaces the currently loaded document with a new Document object. So what you're doing with your code is *replacing* the original document with one that only contains the string 'You just executed javascript code'.

So if you want to use `document.write` to place text inline, you would have to use it like so:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>We are in HTML now</p>
  <script>
    document.write('You just executed javascript code');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to insert text into the document after it has finished loading, you'll need to use another method, like `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Neon Flash,
               I have done some work on your problem.I also research about where is the problem then i found some interesting points hope this will help you
[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

or you can use

Usually, instead of doing

```
document.write
someElement.innerHTML
document.createElement with an someElement.appendChild.
```

You can also consider using a library like jQuery and using the modification functions in there: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 1):

Document.write is replacing the contents inside your body tag.

Try something like this.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display()
{
 document.getElementById("text-from-js").innerHTML = "You just executed JavaScript code";
 return true;
}
</script>

<body onload="display();">
<p>We are in HTML now</p>
<p id="text-from-js"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers said. `document.write` cannot be used for your purpose. And I strongly 
recommend that you don't use it anywhere. Its a bad practice.

For your purpose prepending/appending to `document.body.innerHTML`

ex: `document.body.innerHTML += 'You just executed javascript code';`

or something like

`document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('You just executed javascript code'))`

should do.